# When using Python multiprocessing what counts as I/O and what counts as CPU limitations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

This is a general question.  I have developed some code, which was initially just a long series of commands. Once it was working well, I tried to speed up the execution time using the multiprocessing module of Python.  However, there seems to be little benefit as the old serial code and the new parallel code take almost exactly the same amount of time to process a given list of files.

To provide some details.  The code identifies a list of files, and for each file:

- Uses regex module to find codes for the start and end of the data
- extracts data to a pandas df
- slices part of the df and creates a numpy array and data spline
- extracts some values (max, min etc) from the numpy data
- plots the spline using matplotlib

The serial version of the script iterates through a list of files, while the multiprocessing version of the script essentially passes a list of files to a pool.map function (which I think then assigns a file per cpu).

I knew that the I/O operations do not scale well with the multiprocessing module. But I thought the only I/O operation here is the original opening and reading of each file.  Is my understanding of what constitutes I/O mistaken?  I've also read that numpy doesn't play well with multiprocessing which may also be part of the issue.

Actually, it has occurred to me while writing this, that I/O refers to read and writes to memory NOT just to disk (I think the penny has dropped).  This script does a lot of calcs and generation of new arrays, and new lists so now I'm thinking all of these represent I/O maneuvers and that's why there is no improvement?

So, I'm not really asking for a fix, more just to put me straight if my understanding is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: eh, your intuitive understanding of IO is good enough frankly. The issue that you probably didn't quite consider is perhaps simply that your task itself may not take a lot of time on each file. Also, its always about the ratio of actual time taken for the IO vs the cpu calculations. You can have 1 IO task and 50 calculations, but still end up being IO bound if the calculations themselves are fast. Now, when a task itself is quick overall, the overhead added by creating multiple processes takes away a lot of the benefits of multiprocessing.

Comment: What is the CPU utilization on your machine when the multiprocess code is running?  How many CPU cores do you have, and how many are busy when the code is running?  Which stage of your code (the bulleted points) do you think takes the most time when running serially?

Comment: I think Paritsoh may be right, there are a lot of files, but the amount of data being processed is small, maybe 200 data points which is expanded to around 1000 points using a cubic spline.  So for this script, the files are processed pretty quickly already (around 4 files per sec).   John - I'm running a 6 core on MacOS, but I find the CPU reporting lags when I run the script, and all cores show similar activity.  Also, I've always assumed it was the splining that was the slowest part of the process but I've never timed each section, so maybe I need to do more testing.